# NullPointerException while scrolling a ListView using espresso

Tags: android, android-listview, functional-testing, picasso, android-espresso

I have a ListView which its items each have an ImageView. I am loading the photos from the net into each image view using [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

I am trying to write a functional test for this ListView using [espresso](https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/wiki/Espresso). After struggling a bit I figured out I can scroll to an item in a ListView using:

```
onData(instanceOf(Item.class))
            .inAdapterView(allOf(withId(android.R.id.list), isDisplayed()))
            .atPosition(14)
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

After I ran the test the list would scroll to that item but would crash with the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1052)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1594)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1987)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1744)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:467)
    at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopUntil(UiControllerImpl.java:383)
    at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.base.UiControllerImpl.loopMainThreadForAtLeast(UiControllerImpl.java:368)
    at se.saltside.monterosa.util.ViewMatchers$4.perform(ViewMatchers.java:117)
    at com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.run(ViewInteraction.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5149)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:605)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

<s>After investigating, going through the code and some trial I narrowed down the source of the problem to the line where the images are being loaded in my adapter's `getView` using `Picasso`:</s>

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(ad.getDefaultImage().getThumbnailUrl()).into(imageView);
```

Any ideas on why this would happen and how to fix it?

**Note:**

- I have also tried implementing my own ViewAction which would scroll to a given item in a ListView. But I got the same result.
- The stacktrace above is from android 4.4.2 CyagonenMod version. On 4.4.4 Nexus the stack trace is the same except the title which gives a bit more info:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference`

**Update:**

It seems that the problem is bigger than just picasso. If I comment out picasso, the tests fail on average 1 out of 5 times and with picasso it fails 4 out of 5 times. I even over simplified my `getView` to see what happens, and it sill fails about once in every 5 runs:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View view;
        if (convertView == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(layoutResId, parent, false);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        return view;
}
```

Comment: What version of Android is the stacktrace from?

Comment: I tested it on several devices including:

4.4.2. CyagonenMod & 4.4.4 Nexus. On the later the title of the exception is: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.view.View.getVisibility()' on a null object reference`

Comment: The error also occurs if you removing the `isDisplayed()` check in `inAdapterView`? May you attach the list view after the data is available.